# syntax error , while/do expression,

Tags: java, compiler-errors, do-while

```
package hw.loops.co.il;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopsTargilMedium3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
            num = input.nextInt();

            if (num%2==0) {
                System.out.println("The number " + num + " is ZUGI");
            }   
            else {
                System.out.println("The number " + num + " is E-ZUGI");

                num++;
            } while (num!=-1);
            System.out.println("loop stoped");
        }
    }
}
```

Receiving this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:
Unresolved compilation problem:
    Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete DoStatement
```

Comment: As your indentation indicates, you have `while` _inside_ the `do` block, not at the end of it.

Comment: You are not doing a do-while, you are doing an if-else-while .

Answer (score 1):

you have misplaced a closing bracket before while:

```
..
      } //<-- missing this
    }while (num!=-1);
                System.out.println("loop stoped");
...
```

Comment: Not quite "miss", the number tallies, but the position is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class LoopsTargilMedium3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
            num = input.nextInt();

            if (num%2==0) {
                System.out.println("The number " + num + " is ZUGI");
            }   
            else {
                System.out.println("The number " + num + " is E-ZUGI");

                num++;
            } 
            System.out.println("loop stoped");
        }while (num!=-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think "loop stoped" is supposed to be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
please check do while loop syntax
//--------------------------
do {
     // statements
} while (expression);

---------------------//


import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopsTargilMedium3 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
            num = input.nextInt();

            if (num%2==0) {
                System.out.println("The number " + num + " is ZUGI");
            }   
            else {
                System.out.println("The number " + num + " is E-ZUGI");

                num++;
            } 


        }

        while (num!=-1);
 System.out.println("loop stoped");



    }
}
```